# iPhone XR stuck on update

Tags: iphone, software-update, bug, auto-update

Apple iPhone XR gets stuck on update. Usual reset (quickly press and release Volume Up, quickly press and release Volume Down, press and hold side button) doesn't help.

I found [this issue on apple forum](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250064134) unanswered with a lot of people having it:

> Apple iphone XR frozen during software update. Unresponsive during
>   reboot try. Black screen with Apple Logo . Can not even reboot. What
>   is the Next step ?

So I decided to provide an answer here which I've got by chatting with Apple Support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the last line. It similar, but different:

1. Press and quickly release the Volume Up button.
2. Press and quickly release the Volume Down button.
3. Then, **press and hold the Side button until you see the recovery mode screen**

Then iPhone will get into restore mode and you'll be able to proceed by connecting it to your PC/Mac with iTunes and then choosing Restore and Update.